# mysql select one value as another value from same table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that looks like this, how can i pull out the categoryParent  name instead of id, i can do this buy joining it on to itself

[image]

I can get it to work with an inner join but is there a simpler way of doing it

this is the inner join that works but i feel like there would be an easier way to do this:

```
SELECT `tblCategories`.`categoryId`, `tblCategories`.`categoryName`,
`test`.`categoryName`
FROM `tblCategories`
INNER JOIN `tblCategories` as `test`
ON `tblCategories`.`categoryParent`=`test`.`categoryId`
```

Comment: Show us the query you're working with so far

Comment: That's actually the best way of doing that. Why are you unhappy with that?

Answer (score 0):

You would have to join the tables together, either that or add another column called parentname and have it as a foreign key to link to your parent table parentname column.